# Removing unnecessary nodes in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a graph that has two distinct classes of nodes, class A nodes and class B nodes.

Class A nodes are not connected to any other A nodes and class B nodes aren’t connected to any other B nodes, but B nodes are connected to A nodes and vice versa. Some B nodes are connected to lots of A nodes and most A nodes are connected to lots of B nodes.

I want to eliminate as many of the A nodes as possible from the graph.

I must keep all of the B nodes, and they must still be connected to at least one A node (preferably only one A node).

I can eliminate an A node when it has no B nodes connected only to it. Are there any algorithms that could find an optimal, or at least close to optimal, solution for which A nodes I can remove?

Comment: Way too broad for SO, which is about coding. Research algorithms and maths over on one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Old, Incorrect Answer, But Start Here**

First, you need to recognize that you have a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). That is, you can colour the nodes red and blue such that no edges connect a red node to a red node or a blue node to a blue node.

Next, recognize that you're trying to solve a [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover). From Wikipedia:

> In the mathematical discipline of graph theory, a vertex cover (sometimes node cover) of a graph is a set of vertices such that each edge of the graph is incident to at least one vertex of the set. The problem of finding a minimum vertex cover is a classical optimization problem in computer science and is a typical example of an NP-hard optimization problem that has an approximation algorithm.

Since you have a special graph, it's reasonable to think that maybe the NP-hard doesn't apply to you. This thought brings us to [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) which relates the maximum matching problem to the minimum vertex cover problem. Once you know this, you can apply the [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to solve the problem in *O(|E|√|V|)* time, though you'll probably need to jigger it a bit to ensure you keep all the *B* nodes.

**New, Correct Answer**

It turns out this jiggering is the creation of a "constrained bipartitate graph vertex cover problem", which asks us if there is a vertex cover that uses less than *a* A-nodes and less than *b* B-nodes. The problem is NP-complete, so that's a no go. The jiggering was hard than I thought!

But using less than the minimum number of nodes isn't the constraint we want. We want to ensure that the minimum number of A-nodes is used and the maximum number of B-nodes.

Kőnig's theorem, above, is a special case of the maximum flow problem. Thinking about the problem in terms of flows brings us pretty quickly to [minimum-cost flow problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).

In these problems we're given a graph whose edges have specified capacities and unit costs of transport. The goal is to find the minimum cost needed to move a supply of a given quantity from an arbitrary set of source nodes to an arbitrary set of sink nodes.

It turns out your problem can be converted into a minimum-cost flow problem. To do so, let us generate a source node that connects to all the *A* nodes and a sink node that connects to all the *B* nodes.

Now, let us make the cost of using a *Source->A* edge equal to 1 and give all other edges a cost of zero. Further, let us make the capacity of the *Source->A* edges equal to infinity and the capacity of all other edges equal to 1.

This looks like the following:

[image: Costs in a bipartite graph]

The red edges have Cost=1, Capacity=Inf. The blue edges have Cost=0, Capacity=1.

Now, solving the minimum flow problem becomes equivalent to using as few red edges as possible. Any red edge that isn't used allocates 0 flow to its corresponding A node and that node can be removed from the graph. Conversely, each B node can only pass 1 unit of flow to the sink, so all B nodes must be preserved in order for the problem to be solved.

Since we've recast your problem into this standard form, we can leverage existing tools to get a solution; namely, [Google's Operation Research Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow).

Doing so gives the following answer to the above graph:

[image: Usage in a bipartiate graph]

The red edges are unused and the black edges are used. Note that if a red edge emerges from the source the A-node it connects to generates no black edges. Note also that each B-node has at least one in-coming black edge. This satisfies the constraints you posed.

We can now detect the A-nodes to be removed by looking for *Source->A* edges with zero usage.

**Source Code**

The source code necessary to generate the foregoing figures and associated solutions is as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#Documentation: https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow
#Install dependency: pip3 install ortools

from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.graph import pywrapgraph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import random
import sys

def GenerateGraph(Acount,Bcount):
  assert Acount>5
  assert Bcount>5 

  G = nx.DiGraph() #Directed graph

  source_node = Acount+Bcount
  sink_node   = source_node+1

  for a in range(Acount):
    for i in range(random.randint(0.2*Bcount,0.3*Bcount)): #Connect to 10-20% of the Bnodes
      b = Acount+random.randint(0,Bcount-1) #In the half-open range [0,Bcount). Offset from A's indices
      G.add_edge(source_node, a,         capacity=99999, unit_cost=1, usage=1)
      G.add_edge(a,           b,         capacity=1,     unit_cost=0, usage=1)         
      G.add_edge(b,           sink_node, capacity=1,     unit_cost=0, usage=1)
      G.node[a]['type'] = 'A'
      G.node[b]['type'] = 'B'

  G.node[source_node]['type']   = 'source'
  G.node[sink_node]['type']     = 'sink'
  G.node[source_node]['supply'] = Bcount
  G.node[sink_node]['supply']   = -Bcount

  return G

def VisualizeGraph(graph, color_type):
  gcopy = graph.copy()

  for p, d in graph.nodes(data=True):
    if d['type']=='source':
      source = p
    if d['type']=='sink':
      sink = p    

  Acount = len([1 for p,d in graph.nodes(data=True) if d['type']=='A'])
  Bcount = len([1 for p,d in graph.nodes(data=True) if d['type']=='B'])

  if color_type=='usage':
    edge_color = ['black' if d['usage']>0 else 'red' for u,v,d in graph.edges(data=True)]
  elif color_type=='unit_cost':
    edge_color = ['red' if d['unit_cost']>0 else 'blue' for u,v,d in graph.edges(data=True)]

  Ai  = 0
  Bi  = 0
  pos = dict()
  for p,d in graph.nodes(data=True):
    if d['type']=='source':
      pos[p] = (0, Acount/2)
    elif d['type']=='sink':
      pos[p] = (3, Bcount/2)
    elif d['type']=='A':
      pos[p] = (1, Ai)
      Ai += 1
    elif d['type']=='B':
      pos[p] = (2, Bi)
      Bi += 1      

  nx.draw(graph, pos=pos, edge_color=edge_color, arrows=False)

  plt.show()



def GenerateMinCostFlowProblemFromGraph(graph):
  start_nodes = []
  end_nodes   = []
  capacities  = []
  unit_costs  = []

  min_cost_flow = pywrapgraph.SimpleMinCostFlow()

  for node,neighbor,data in graph.edges(data=True):
    min_cost_flow.AddArcWithCapacityAndUnitCost(node, neighbor, data['capacity'], data['unit_cost'])

  supply = len([1 for p,d in graph.nodes(data=True) if d['type']=='B'])

  for p, d in graph.nodes(data=True):
    if (d['type']=='source' or d['type']=='sink') and 'supply' in d:
      min_cost_flow.SetNodeSupply(p, d['supply'])

  return min_cost_flow



def ColorGraphEdgesByUsage(graph, min_cost_flow):
  for i in range(min_cost_flow.NumArcs()):
    graph[min_cost_flow.Tail(i)][min_cost_flow.Head(i)]['usage'] = min_cost_flow.Flow(i)

def main():
  """MinCostFlow simple interface example."""

  # Define four parallel arrays: start_nodes, end_nodes, capacities, and unit costs
  # between each pair. For instance, the arc from node 0 to node 1 has a
  # capacity of 15 and a unit cost of 4.

  Acount = 20
  Bcount = 20
  graph = GenerateGraph(Acount, Bcount)

  VisualizeGraph(graph, 'unit_cost')

  min_cost_flow = GenerateMinCostFlowProblemFromGraph(graph)

  # Find the minimum cost flow between node 0 and node 4.
  if min_cost_flow.Solve() != min_cost_flow.OPTIMAL:
    print('Unable to find a solution! It is likely that one does not exist for this input.')
    sys.exit(-1)

  print('Minimum cost:', min_cost_flow.OptimalCost())

  ColorGraphEdgesByUsage(graph, min_cost_flow)

  VisualizeGraph(graph, 'usage')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has helped me move in the right direction. Maybe I don’t understand it fully. The thing is the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm, from Wikipedia, “produces as output a maximum cardinality matching - a set of as many edges as possible with the property that no two edges share an endpoint.” I need it to be almost the opposite of that where I want as many edges to share an endpoint as possible with those endpoints being the A nodes. Each B node should, ideally, have only one edge. This should hopefully eliminate as many A nodes as possible.

Comment: @ggrant: My apologies, the idea I proposed would not have easily led you to a solution. I've revised my answer with a working solution.

Comment: @ggrant: Did that help?

Comment: Yes that did! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Despite this is an old question, I see it has not been correctly answered yet.

An analogous question to this one has also been answered earlier in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/839886).

The problem you are presenting here is indeed the Minimum Set Cover Problem, which is one of the well-known NP-hard problems. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), the Minimum Set Cover Problem can be formulated as:

> Given a set of elements {1,2,...,n} (called the universe) and a collection S of m sets whose union equals the universe, the set cover problem is to identify the smallest sub-collection of S whose union equals the universe. For example, consider the universe U={1,2,3,4,5} and the collection of sets S={{1,2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{4,5}}. Clearly the union of S is U. However, we can cover all of the elements with the following, smaller number of sets: {{1,2,3},{4,5}}.

In your formulation, B nodes represent the elements in the universe, A nodes represent the sets and edges between A nodes and B nodes determine which elements (B nodes) belong to each set (A node). Then, the minimum set cover is equivalent to the minimum number of A nodes so that they are connected to all B nodes. Consequently, the maximum number of A nodes which can be removed from the graph while being connected to every B node are those which do not belong to the minimum set cover.

Since it is NP-hard, there is no polinomial time algorithm for computing the optimum, but a simple greedy algorithm can efficiently provide approximate solutions with tight bounds to the optimum. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm):

> There is a greedy algorithm for polynomial time approximation of set covering that chooses sets according to one rule: at each stage, choose the set that contains the largest number of uncovered elements.

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer following the suggestion.